PNPM error: There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing
I am following along a nextjs tutorial. I just did the initial setup, installed packages, every time I run
pnpm dev
below error shows up
 ⚠ ./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!D:\NextJs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\lib\is-error.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!D:\NextJs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\is-hydration-error.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\lib\is-error.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!D:\nextjs\tutorial\leerobagain\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\is-hydration-error.js|app-pages-browser
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/is-hydration-error.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/helpers/use-error-handler.js
./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-

i am using pnpm as package manager.
Below is the package.json file
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.2.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  }
}


basic boilerplate for nextjs

layout.js

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );`your text`
}



page.js

export default function Page() {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}


FYI: I have already tried removing node_modules, and .next folder and reinstalling packages.
